# May a Jew own/operate a blog open to comments?

Tags: halacha, technology, internet, current-events, lashon-hara-slander

In light of [recent events](http://finkorswim.com/2013/04/19/the-difference-between-hirhurim-and-the-yated-a-defense-of-r-gil-student/) I would like to know if a Jew may own and operate a blog or website which is open to comments if it is found that comments can often contain lashon hara, rechilus or motzei shem ra. Is there an obligation to moderate and remove comments that the owner feels violate those issurim?

Would such a site/blog run afowl of injunctions not to perpetuate sin(ners?) such as m'saiyah l'yideh avaira (helping the hand of sin), not placing a stumbling block before a blind person, kol yisroel areivim (all Jews are guarantors one for the other) etc.?

Comment: Can you suggest why you think it might be prohibited?

Comment: And regardless, even if the comments were to maintain lashon hara, etc., you're still able to moderate them and eliminate comments you feel may violate your halakhic obligations.

Comment: May a Jew speak in a public forum or hold a public position (like rabbi), when it is found that community members can often speak lashon hara, rechilus or motzei shem ra?

Comment: @DoubleAA m'saiyah l'yideh avaira, lifnei eiver, kol yisroel areivim... and any other issue which prevents you from being complicit in another person's sin.

Comment: @SethJ I don't see the comparison. you are talking about a public forum, i'm talking about a privately owned one.

Comment: if downvoters could explain why they feel the question is poor i'm happy to edit it

Comment: May a Jew speak at a members-only gathering? May a rabbi or other Jewish leader speak privately among friends nowadays when anything anyone says could be picked up on video and posted online to be ridiculed or used to ridicule others?

Comment: Can you suggest a reason why you think it would a problem to own or operate a site like the one you describe. The newly added second half of the question makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @SethJ Ok, I hope this helps

Comment: @SethJ, there are halachic issues about speaking when it is likely that others will come to speak loshon hara.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, of course there are. But at a certain point there has to be a line drawn. Are we now obligated, because of modern technology, to keep our mouths shut, especially if we reach positions of prominence?